# How MongoDB is balancing loading between two routers or more ? From application?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have php application and now I want to migrate from mysql to mongodb. All good from replica to sharding, but if I have several routers (example ip:10001,ip2:10001) how balanced betwwen two routers for failover. Does MongoDB have some what I must know know to connecting to all routers , or I must will write something on PHP with random connecting?
Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general way to do this using the MongoClient class of your driver is to specify a URI form [connection string](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/) or other form of a seed list when establishing your connection:

This would typically be in the form:

```
"mongodb://username:password@ip:1001,ip2:1001/database"
```

With the individual hosts separated by commas.

The driver will then take care of failover should one of those `mongos` instances not be available.

If you are actually looking for "balancing" connections between the two then that is something not provided at the driver level and you would need to look at other solutions.

Comment: Thank you. Please tell me - if I will use this method, what will happen 1)all queries will go throw first router(ip:10001) and if it down queries will go throw second router and in turn? OR 2) all queries goes through both routers and if which one of them down - another working routers will takes all queries?